# no text when running Age of Empires 2 in Linux

Tags: wine

My game file is downloaded from [here](http://u2.xainjo.com//lh/diguoshidai2zhengfuzhe.zip)

My wine version is:

wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)

I run the following command:

`wine age2.exe`

but I get:
[no text in game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/374ss.jpg)
[image]

I have put `simsun.ttc`
/home/appleyuchi/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts

and installed with the following script

`REGEDIT4`

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink]`

`"Lucida Sans Unicode"="simsun.ttc"`

`"Microsoft Sans Serif"="simsun.ttc"`

`"MS Sans Serif"="simsun.ttc"`

`"Tahoma"="simsun.ttc"`

`"Tahoma Bold"="simsun.ttc"`

`"SimSun"="simsun.ttc"`

`"Arial"="simsun.ttc"`

`"Arial Black"="simsun.ttc"`

---

and run `wine regedit xxx.reg`

and `wine age2.exe` again

-----------error information I get from command--------------

0009:err:dplay:DP_InitializeDPSP DP SP Initialization failed:

DPERR_UNAVAILABLE

0009:err:dplay:DirectPlayCreate Failed to Initialize SP: DPERR_UNAVAILABLE

0009:err:dplay:IDirectPlay4Impl_InitializeConnection Unable to load

service provider {44eaa760-cb68-11cf-9c4e-00a0c905425e}

0009:err:dplay:DirectPlayCreate Failed to Initialize SP: DPERR_UNAVAILABLE

0009:err:dplay:IDirectPlay4Impl_InitializeConnection Unable to load

service provider {0f1d6860-88d9-11cf-9c4e-00a0c905425e}

-----------------------error end------------------------------------------

But still so much `???`in my game,

could you tell me how to solve it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: My guess is that is expected fonts you don't have installed. You haven't mentioned your release, but do you have *mscorefonts* installed?

Comment: Thanks for your replies,I have updated my description~

Comment: We still don't know what OS/release you are running.  (the version of `wine` you mentioned is listed for more than a single release)

Comment: My OS is ubuntu20.04 the,the version of wine is got from the command`wine --version`,thanks for your replies~!

Comment: Is there no error output from running it via `wine age2.exe`?

Comment: There really exist error information，but it‘s about video play by google.I have added the content of error information above.Thanks for your replies.